# Referencing arrays in object using $.each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

This code;

```
$.each( formValues, function(index, array) { 
        console.log("index: ",index," array: ",array);
        });
```

Outputs this in the console;

```
index:  0  array:  {name: "check2", value: "checked"}
index:  1  array:  {name: "text1", value: "4"}
```

How do I adjust the each statement so that I can target the 'name' and\or 'value' values individually, in the logged array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that your `array` variable is misnamed, which is potentially causing your confusion - it's an object. As such you can just access the property, ie `array.name` or `array.value`

Comment: @MarmaCinas - that's confusing and [incorrect according to the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Comment: @MarmaCinas - if you delete your comment(s), I will too... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.` to access value from object

```
$.each(formValues, function(index, array) {
  console.log(array.name); // will output name
  console.log(array.value); // Will output value
});
```

Comment: It's implied, but it's worth being explicit: The value of `array` is actually an _object_.  You could also use `array['name']` to access the values.